# Help to Change the Language for SQL Activity - Getdate

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I tried to do a simple sintax, but i have a problem with the language and "getdate"

I'm Brazillian and have an automation that update a Data Extension (Primary Key is month) with a FTP integration that the data always arrives in portuguese. But one day before this automation works, two fields (the month and the number of records from another DE) have to update. My sintax below:

Like the month in the archive arrives in portuguese, i needs that the DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) arrived in PT-BR. Is it possible?

```
select DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS [Month],
count(*) As [Field1]
from [Clients_DE]
```

Comment: is it important that the data in the data extension has a date formatting or is it important that the emails / pages showing the date have the date formatting?

Usually, It is best to keep the data as standardized as possible in the actual data field, and format it to the relevant context where needed using AMPScript. FormatDate() function should allow exactly what you are asking for.

https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/ has this example:

set @frFRDate = properCase(FormatDate(@dateString,"l","","fr-FR"))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a translation table data extension to map PT-BR month names to their english equivalent. Then you could use the "DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS [Month]" value to join to this DE and get the PT-BR name.